# Появление div при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на `div` с порядковым номером появлялся `div` с таким же порядковым номером?

Например нажимаем на `div`:

```
<div id="Corpushead 1">Дом2</div>
```

Появляется `div` с

```
<div id="hideCorpus 1">
```

нажимаем на `div`:

```
<div id="Corpushead 2">Дом2</div>
```

Появляется `div` с

```
<div id="hideCorpus 2">
```

а первый пропадает и так далее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let corpusheads = document.getElementsByClassName('corpushead');

for(let i = 0; i < corpusheads.length; i++){
  corpusheads[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    let corpuss = document.getElementsByClassName('corpus');
    let id = corpusheads[i].id.split('-')[1];
    for(let corpus of corpuss){
        corpus.style.display = 'none';
    }
    corpus = document.getElementById(`corpus-${id}`);
    
    corpus.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.corpushead{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.corpus{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="corpushead" id="head-1">Дом1</div>
<div class="corpus" id="corpus-1">1</div>

<div class="corpushead" id="head-2">Дом2</div>
<div class="corpus" id="corpus-2">2</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. то что нужно.

Comment: @Swet да незачто, только отметь пожалуйста галочкой что ответ правильный